# Is the Kafich edition of the Rambam's peirush on Mishnah to Mesecht Keilim available online anywhere?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet

I'm trying to find the Kafich edition of the Rambam's peirush on Mishnah to Mesecht Keilim. Is it available online anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kafih edition of the Rambam's Peirush on Mishna is available in its' entirety on Otzar HaChachma. You can access the commentary to Mesechet Keilim [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=155224&width=0&scroll=0&udid=0&pagenum=23).